# SSH Server cannot start in my WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) recently, most of it works fine, but there is one problem here: My SSH server doesn't work:

```
root@X00194181:~# service ssh start
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
sshd: ../sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:2591: getaddrinfo: Assertion `(__extension__ ({ const struct in6_addr *__a = (const struct in6_addr *) (sin6->sin6_addr.__in6_u.__u6_addr32); __a->__in6_u.__u6_addr32[0] == 0 && __a->__in6_u.__u6_addr32[1] == 0 && __a->__in6_u.__u6_addr32[2] == __bswap_32 (0xffff); }))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The Related code can be retrieved from

```
apt-get source eglibc6
```

the file is eglibc-2.19/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c, the related assertion code is:

```
/* We have to convert the address.  The socket is IPv6 and the request is for IPv4.  */
struct sockaddr_in6 *sin6
    = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) &results[i].source_addr;
struct sockaddr_in *sin
    = (struct sockaddr_in *) &results[i].source_addr;
assert(IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(sin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr32));//assertion failed here
```

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: You don't say which Windows Build you are using. Anything before Creators Update will cause things like `ssh` to fail. Also which release of Ubuntu are you using? If its 14.04 there will be problems like this.

Answer (score 3):

I tried `sudo service ssh start -4` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try full reinstall of WSL:

- lxrun /uninstall /full /y
- lxrun /install

then get root shell:

- sudo su

install ssh:

- apt-get install ssh

generate ssh host Keys:

- /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A

and try to start ssh

- service ssh start

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo service ssh --full-restart
```

This worked for me.